# How to remove the last line in python to keep it at exactly 10 lines

Tags: python

I have a text file that already prepends until it has 10 lines

```
    Line 10
    Line 9
    Line 8
    Line 7
    Line 6
    Line 5
    Line 4
    Line 3
    Line 2
    Line 1
```

Now if I prepend more line into this text file. It'll become 11 Line

```
    Line 11
    Line 10
    Line 9
    Line 8
    Line 7
    Line 6
    Line 5
    Line 4
    Line 3
    Line 2
    Line 1
```

And now, I want to remove the Line 1 from the file to keep it only 10 lines long. How do I do that in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have read your lines, you can use slicing before writing them again with:

```
lines = lines[:10]  # Keep 10 first lines
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I wrote the code which is Do the writing in file
and then **I changed** it to What you've asked:

For example this is the Code that do the writing :

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")

lines = ["line 1 ","line 2","line 3","line 4","line 5","line 6","line 7","line 8","line 9","line 10"]
i = len(lines)-1
while( i >= 0):

    f.write(lines[i]+"\n")
    i -= 1
f.close()
```

output :

```
line 10
line 9
line 8
line 7
line 6
line 5
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

**Now I wanna change this to what you've asked (to delete last line):**

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")

lines = ["line 1 ","line 2","line 3","line 4","line 5","line 6","line 7","line 8","line 9","line 10"]

#first of all you have to append new line to you list
lines.append("line 11")
lines = lines[-10:] # this is how you Select 10 last elements

i = len(lines)-1
while( i >= 0):

    f.write(lines[i]+"\n")
    i -= 1


f.close()
```

**Output:**

```
line 11
line 10
line 9
line 8
line 7
line 6
line 5
line 4
line 3
line 2
```

So as a result for selecting **N last elements** of list you can use this Option:

```
anyList = anyList[-N:]
```